# SpriteKit not playing audio file?

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skaction, skaudionode

I have made a custom class, SoundNode, to handle the playing of audio files. For now, it only plays the default "A2.mp3"

```
class SoundNode : SKSpriteNode{
func playSound(){
    run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("A2", waitForCompletion: false))
    }
}
```

I then call the *playSound* method in my SKScene like so:

```
SoundNode().playSound()
```

**But, the sound never plays??** I have made sure the file exists within my project and have also double checked the file name to make sure it is correct. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SoundNode` is a kind of node. Every node only works when it is in a scene. Just creating a `SoundNode` and calling `playSound` does not do anything because the node has not been added to the scene!

To make this work, just add it to the scene:

```
let node = SoundNode()
self.addChild(node)
node.playSound()
```

Also, I suggest that `SoundNode` should not inherit `SKSpriteNode` because it is obviously not a sprite i.e. something that can be seen on screen. Just make it inherit `SKNode`.

Comment: Worked perfectly!